# python list: double each element in a list while maintaining the structure

Tags: python, list

How do write a function to double each element in a list while maintaining the structure of the list?

For example:

```
f([1, [2, [3]]]) => [2, [4, [6]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach could be:

```
def double(li):
    try:
        return [double(x) for x in li]
    except:  # li is not iterable, recursion base case
        return 2*li  # or sth. else for non-numerical, non-iterable types
```

Note, however, that this solution 'listifies' all sorts of iterables. A more sophisticated version that maintains the types of your iterables, thus can handle any nested structure of lists, tuples, sets, etc. would have this line in the try-block:

```
 return type(li)(map(double, li))  # should work in Python 2 and 3
```

This instantiates and returns an object of `li`'s original type (list, tuple, etc.) with a list (Py2) or a map object (Py3) of all doubled elements in `li`.

Comment: I recommend keeping the comprehension, as `map()` returns a `map()` object in Python 3 rather than a `list` like it does in Python 2.

Comment: Ah I see, as a company-restrained Python 2.7 user, those nuances elude me. Thx again ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that the list will be just lists and numbers, you can do this:

```
def double(numberlist):
    return [double(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x * 2 for x in numberlist]
```

If the argument could be any iterable, you can do this:

```
from collections import Iterable
def double(numberlist):
    return [double(x) if isinstance(x, Iterable) else x * 2 for x in numberlist]
```